# enable drop-down list on button click in angular

Tags: angularjs

I am using a button and on clicking it. How can I show drop-down list when user click on search button instead clicking on drop-down menu in angular?

Comment: Will you please share your code ?

Comment: Please [show your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read the [asking a question guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You'll get better results.

Comment: <a><button>Search</button></a>                     <select>          <option value="">10</option>
                       <option value="">20</option>
                
                   </select>

Comment: now, if I click on button then only I need option of the select

Comment: why don't you pass a model to your select element ? You will get model value in ngclick

Comment: You mean, like this
<a ng-click=""><button>Search</button></a>  <select ng-model="dropDown"> <option value="">10</option> <option value="">20</option> </select>

Comment: In my requirement Initially it will show only search button not drop-down. Now, I need to show select list option directly when user click on search button instead of clicking on drop-down list. So I can get options when I click on search button and I can select any of them and once selected one option need to show another drop-down. Here is my code
    <select><option value="">A</option><option value="">B</option>
    <option value="">C</option>
    <option value="">D</option>
</select>

here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8bhvhq62/3/.